# Safecracker and Geofinder. Can't Get Entries Created from Safecracker to Display

Tags: safecracker, geofinder

I have been working with Safecracker/GeoFinder and the entries created directly from the backend (without safecracker) display perfectly fine in the Geofinder Results, but entries created through the form on my site (with safecracker) won't show up in GeoFinder.

Is there anything I have to do to get entries created through safecracker to display in GeoFinder Results that I may be missing?

**Safecracker 2.1 (Updated):**

```
    {exp:safecracker
channel="personal_trainer_directory"
return="/member/profile"
entry_id=""
safecracker_head="no"
use_live_url="no"
url_title=""
class="geotagger"
}

    <input type="hidden" id="trainer_longitude" name="trainer_longitude" value="{trainer_longitude}">
    <input type="hidden" id="trainer_latitude" name="trainer_latitude" value="{trainer_latitude}">

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
    <label for="title">Name</label>
    <span class="directions">The name to be displayed in your listing.</span>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
    <label for="url_title">URL Title</label>
    <span class="directions">Put a dash between first and last name. example: "john-smith"</span>
    <input type="text" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75" size="50">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection trainer-photo clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_photo">Photo</label>
        <span class="directions">The photo to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <input type="file" name="trainer_photo" id="trainer_photo" value="{trainer_photo}">
    </div>


    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_email">Email Address</label>
        <span class="directions">The email address to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_email" id="trainer_email" value="{trainer_email}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_rate">Rate</label>
        <span class="directions">The rate to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_rate" id="trainer_rate" value="{trainer_rate}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_phone">Phone Number</label>
        <span class="directions">The phone number to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_phone" id="trainer_phone" value="{trainer_phone}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_address">Street Address</label>
        <span class="directions">This will NOT be displayed in your listing. Only for search Purposes.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_address" id="trainer_address" value="{trainer_address}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_city">City</label>
        <span class="directions">The city to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_city" id="trainer_city" value="{trainer_city}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_state">State</label>
        <span class="directions">The state to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <select name="trainer_state">
            {options:trainer_state}
                <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
            {/options:trainer_state}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_zip">Zip Code</label>
        <span class="directions">The zip code to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_zip" id="trainer_zip" value="{trainer_zip}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_about">Trainer Information</label>
        <span class="directions">Information about the trainer to be displayed in your listing.</span>
        <textarea id="trainer_about" name="trainer_about" dir="{text_direction}" rows="{rows}">{trainer_about}</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_certifications">Certifications</label>
        <span class="directions">Your certifications to be displayed in your listing. Separate with commas.</span>
        <input type="text" name="trainer_certifications" id="trainer_certifications" value="{trainer_certifications}">
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_areas_of_expertise">Areas of Expertise</label>
        <span class="directions">Your areas of expertise to be displayed in your listing. Separate with commas.</span>
        <textarea type="text" name="trainer_areas_of_expertise" dir="{text_direction}" id="trainer_areas_of_expertise">{trainer_areas_of_expertise}</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_specials">Specials</label>
        <span class="directions">Your specials to be displayed in your listing. Separate with commas.</span>
        <textarea type="text" name="trainer_specials" dir="{text_direction}" id="trainer_specials">{trainer_specials}</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="formsection clearfix">
        <label for="trainer_gym_affiliates">Gym Affiliates</label>
        <span class="directions">Your gym affiliates to be displayed in your listing. Separate with commas.</span>
        <textarea type="text" name="trainer_gym_affiliates" dir="{text_direction}" id="trainer_gym_affiliates">{trainer_gym_affiliates}</textarea>
    </div>

    {field:trainer_geocode}

    <div id="thankyousave">
        <input type="submit"  class="small red button radius" name="save" value="Save Settings" />
    </div>
{/exp:safecracker}
```

and here is the fields in the backend: http://d.pr/KeOa

Comment: Do the entries have different statuses? Or future dated entry dates? Post your code and versions.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl I edited and added my safecracker form, I'm using safecracker 2.1 and geofinder 2.2.  After looking at it further, the `longitude` and `latitude` fields end up being blank, so I think thats why its not displaying in the search results but the page is being created fine.  any idea on how to pass the values for those 2 things to EE so they dont end up being blank?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell your hidden input fields for longitude and latitude may not be correctly named.

Try changing to:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="trainer_longitude" value="{trainer_longitude}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="trainer_latitude" value="{trainer_latitude}" />
```

Comment: I now have what you entered above, but with `hidden` it still doesnt populate the fields so what i did was change them to `text`, and i entered the values for both to see if it would work and it worked fine.. so just need to figure out a way to populate those fields before the form gets submitted

Comment: You'll need to use another addon for the GeoCoding. Try GeoTagger. It says it works with SafeCracker: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/geotagger

Comment: I updated the main post code but longitude and latitude is still coming up as empty.. really confused since I'm not sure whats incorrect with safecracker/geotagger.. is there anything you see that is incorrect?

Comment: Did you change the field types for your longitude and latitude fields to Geotagger fields? Make sure you have "Auto-tag" set for the Geotagger mode on the field settings. Make sure you map the field latitude and longitude fields. Go through the docs for adding a new field step by step: http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/geotagger/

Comment: my settings have been set up like this http://d.pr/lmFy  Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't actually used GeoTagger... Is GeoTagging working correctly when an entry is added via the CP? If not, I'd say settings aren't correct and you should retrace your steps. If yes, and not in the Safecracker form, then some issue still in the form code... doublecheck field names... That's about as much help as I can be unfortunately.

Comment: yea entrys work perfectly fine when created through the CP, it sjust through safecracker where I'm having difficulities so i'll double check the form code and field names.. it may be something little that i just cant spot but hopefully I'll get it working soon! Thanks!

Comment: One thing too... make sure you are working with the most recent version of EE and Safecracker module...